# how to add a specific string to the end of each line of a file, however the strings changes for some blocks

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a big text file that I would need to add the first line of the file to the end of the next lines until it finds another string with the same name, then it would start from the next string adding this to the end of the next lines until it finds another string with the same name again, and so forth... Ex: STRING=TITLE1 it would append the TITLE1 to the end of USER1,USER2,USER3,USER4 and when it finds the TITLE1 again, it would read the next line and the STRING would be TITLE2 now for the next lines until it finds the next TITLE2 again...
Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

```
TITLE1
USER1
USER2
USER3
USER4
TITLE1
TITLE2
USER10
USER20
USER30
USER40
TITLE2
TITLE3
TESTUSER1
TESTUSER2
TESTUSER3
TITLE3
...
```

OUTPUT WOULD BE:

```
USER1 TITLE1
USER2 TITLE1
USER3 TITLE1
USER4 TITLE1
USER10 TITLE2
USER20 TITLE2
USER30 TITLE2
USER40 TITLE2
TESTUSER1 TITLE3
TESTUSER2 TITLE3
TESTUSER3 TITLE3
...
..
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code which is highly encouraged on SO(not my downvote btw), thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The following `awk` script does what you want:

```
awk 's==""{s=$0;next} {if($0==s) s=""; else print $0, s}' yourFile
```

Comment: thanks Socowi... it worked like a charm :) I was struggling when the TITLE changed, I wasn't able to change the string to the next title. Thank you very much !! AAA+++